# Realm Simple Retrieve query returns null?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, cloud

I have one table(Test) in the database,it contains the id(primary key),name,status,checkid.

I am written the simple query to get the record based on the checkid.but sometimes query returns null in android with kotlin.

below is the sample table fields
id = "1",name = "raj",status=0 and checkid="12345" and this is my query

```
val selTest = realm.where<Test>().equalTo("checkid", "12345").findFirst()
```

result always retuns null

Below are the realm db details

```
Instance Address : incredible-soft-bike.us1a.cloud.realm.io
```

Comment: Paste your class `Test` code please

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @QuarK are you insert data through realm studio?

Comment: @Rajesh nope, I through create function using `createObject<entity>()`